# Open a Terminal by StartProcess and write commands to it does not work as expected

Tags: external-calls

Probably my expecations are wrong: I want to open a terminal window on my Xubuntu 20.04 system. Then I want to issue the command `tail -f  ~/M` to display the tail of the file `~/M` which will grow later when I append `$Output` and `$Messages` to it.

The terminal window application on my system is `xfce4-terminal`. Therefore I use the command

```
process = StartProcess @ {$SystemShell, "-c", "xfce4-terminal"};
```

in my Mathematica session. I opens a terminal window. Other than with `RunProcess`, my mathematics session is not paused until the terminal session is finished. Before trying to tee output, I want to verify that I can issue commands into `xfce4-terminal`, e.g.

```
WriteLine[process, "ls -l"]
```

However, I get

```
BinaryWrite::errfile: Could not access file File write failed.
```

I suppose that the error cause is that `WriteLine` writes to the wrong process: `$SystemShell` instead of `xfce4-terminal`.

**How can I issue commands into the opened `xfce4-terminal`?**

Comment: Try the -x or -e options with the `xfce4-terminal` command, I don't have Mma on linux, so can't verify it myself.

Comment: Perhaps another way to achieve what I think you're trying to do is to write your Mathematica output to a file and `tail - f` that file. Or, to write to the `/dev/ttyXXX` socket that the new term is attached to.

Comment: Syed, if I issue `xfce4-terminal` into a xfce4-terminal, another terminal is spawned. If I issue `xfce4-terminal -x ls -l` a terminal flashes up at the task bar, but the command returns without any enduring effect. The same happens, if I issue `xfce4-terminal -e "ls -l"` (this time the ls command included in double quotation marks. Without double quotation marks, the `-e` option returns `xfce4-terminal: Unbekannte Option »-l«
`.

Comment: Carl, this is effectively what I do: `AppendTo[$Output, teeStream = OpenWrite[FileNameJoin[{"~/", "M"}]]]; AppendTo[$Messages, teeStream];`. Then all Print and all messages go to this log file. In order to see the most recent additions to `~/M`, I have to open a terminal window and issue the command `ls -l` to it. That's the background of my question: I want to open the terminal window from Mathematica.

Comment: Try using the suggested options at the time of creating the process, not afterwards.